# setTimeout function is not getting executed in protractor using javascript

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have created a function where i need to read a file after a delay of 2 mins.

```
function checkInLogs(logFilPath, logMessage){

    setTimeout(() => {

        fs.readFile(logFilPath, 'utf8', function (err,data){
            console.log('I am inside the checkInLogs function')
         })

    }, 120000);

    console.log('outside the function');
}
```

I am calling the function with the following code:

```
fileUtil.checkInLogs('D:/Installation/V114_new/be/5.6/rms/bin/logs/CCARms25', '[Port:8090] successfully started');
```

But the problem is code inside the setTimeOut is never getting executed.
On the console i can see the message as :outside the function.
But code inside is not getting executed.
I even tried the function as :

```
function checkInLogs(logFilPath, logMessage){

    fs.exists(logFilPath, function(exists) {
        fs.readFile(logFilPath, 'utf8', function (err,data){
            console.log(data.toString());
            console.log(err.toString());
         })

    })



}
```

and calling it like:

```
setTimeout(function() {
            fileUtil.checkInLogs('D:/Installation/V114_new/be/5.6/rms/bin/logs/CCARms21', '[Port:8090] successfully started')
        }, 120000);
```

But no luck. Code inside the setTimeOut is not getting executed.
Any suggestion/solutions please.

Comment: Is this inside of a protractor test? If so, is this in the test itself or in an `afterEach`?

Comment: Yes, it is inside the protractor test , inside the "it" block .

Answer (score 0):

With the test I think you'll need to tell it to wait first but not with a setTimeout.
This should work pretending the timeouts are long enough in your protractor.conf.

```
it('can wait two min', async ()=>{
  await browser.sleep(120000);

  fileUtil.checkInLogs('D:/Installation/V114_new/be/5.6/rms/bin/logs/CCARms21', '[Port:8090] successfully started');
})
```